# В чём разница между сценой и представлением в PyQt5?

Tags: python, pyqt5, qgraphicsscene, qgraphicsview, qgraphicsitem

В чём разница между **`сценой`** и **`представлением`** в *PyQt5*?

Comment: в PyQt5 есть сцена?

Answer (score 2):

**Graphics View Framework**

`Graphics View`  обеспечивает поверхность для управления и взаимодействия с большим количеством пользовательских 2D-графических элементов, а также виджет для визуализации элементов с поддержкой масштабирования и поворота.

`Графическое представление` использует дерево BSP (Binary Space Partitioning), 
чтобы обеспечить очень быстрое обнаружение элементов, и в результате оно может визуализировать большие сцены в реальном времени, даже с миллионами элементов.

Графическое представление в основном содержит три класса:

- класс примитивов    `QGraphicsItem`,
- класс сцены         `QGraphicsScene`,
- класс представления `QGraphicsView`.

> `Примитивы` размещаются на `сцене`, а содержимое сцены отображается через `представления`.

Примитивы могут быть текстом, рисунками, обычной геометрией или любой другой графикой.
`QGraphicsItem` поддерживает функции:

- события мыши, перемещения, отпускания и двойного щелчка,
  а также, события колесика и события меню, вызываемые щелчком правой кнопкой мыши;
- событие ввода с клавиатуры;
- события перетаскивания;
- обнаружение столкновения.

`QGraphicsRectItem`, `QGraphicsScene` и `QGraphicsView` на имеют свои собственные функции событий.

> Порядок доставки событий -  Вид -> Сцена -> Элемент.

`QGraphicsScene` (Сцена) - предоставляет методы, позволяющие быстро добавлять примитивы.

Сцена также предоставляет множество методов для управления примитивами.

> `QGraphicsView` на самом деле является областью прокрутки.

Если представления меньше размера сцены, в окне будет отображаться полоса прокрутки, 
чтобы пользователь мог наблюдать всю сцену.

Kогда примитивы добавлены и сцена настроена, мы обычно можем вызывать некоторые методы представления для выполнения некоторых преобразований примитивов, таких как увеличение, уменьшение и вращение.

Конечно, представление также предоставляет много методов. 
 Например, вы также можете использовать items() и itemAt() для получения примитивов. 
 Вы также можете установить фон представления, режим кэширования представления,
 режим перетаскивания мышью и т.д.

> Графическое представление основано на декартовой системе координат, 
>   у представлений, сцен и примитивов есть свои **собственные координаты**.

`Координаты вида`(представления) основаны **на верхнем левом углу** как начале координат,
 положительной оси `x` справа и положительной оси `y` вниз 
 (все события мыши **изначально** используют координаты представления).

`Координаты сцены` **центрированы** в начале координат,
 положительная ось x расположена справа, а положительная ось y внизу 
 (координаты сцены описывают положение самого верхнего примитива).

`Координаты примитива` такие же, как координаты сцены.

`QGraphicsView` предоставляет функции отображения `mapToScene()` и `mapFromScene()`, 
 а также методы доступа к элементам `items()` и `itemAt()`.
 Эти функции позволяют отображать точки, прямоугольники, многоугольники и пути 
 между координатами вида и координатами сцены, 
 а также находить элементы на сцене, используя **координаты вида**.

Графическое представление предоставляет функции для преобразования между тремя системами координат и функции преобразования между примитивами.

---

**Резюме**

1. Порядок доставки события:  **View -> Scene -> Element**. 
   Если оно передается между родительским и дочерним классами элемента, 
   порядок передачи от дочернего класса к родительскому классу.
2. Представления, сцены и примитивы имеют свою **собственную систему координат**.
3. Среда графического представления имеет слишком много точек знаний. 
   Чтобы узнать больше https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/graphicsview.html .