# PyQt. Не обрабатывается событие mouseMoveEvent

Tags: python, pyqt, qgraphicsscene, qgraphicsview, mousemoveevent

Вот такой простой код:

```py
import sys
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt6.QtCore import *
from PyQt6.QtGui import *


class RectItem(QGraphicsRectItem):
    def __init__(self, qrectf):
        super().__init__()
        self.qrectf = qrectf
        self.setRect(self.qrectf)
        
    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        print("hello")

class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.qrectf = QRectF(0, 0, 50, 50)
        self.item = RectItem(self.qrectf)
        self.scene = QGraphicsScene()
        self.scene.setSceneRect(0,0,200,300)
        self.scene.addItem(self.item)
        self.canvas = QGraphicsView()
        self.canvas.setScene(self.scene)

        layout = QHBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.canvas)
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Window()
    w.show()
    app.exec()
```

Не могу понять, почему не срабатывает метод `mouseMoveEvent(self, event)`

[Нашел примерно такой же вопрос здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1200469/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D1%81%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8B-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%BC%D1%8B%D1%88%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D0%BE-scene)
Но там ничего не понял.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я  не знаю что вы будите делать дальше с этим простым кодом, но давайте для начала добавим один флаг.

Класс [**QGraphicsRectItem**](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qgraphicsrectitem.html) предоставляет прямоугольный элемент, который можно добавить в QGraphicsScene.

[**List of All Members for QGraphicsRectItem**](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qgraphicsrectitem-members.html)

> QGraphicsItem::[**setFlag**](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qgraphicsitem.html#setFlag)(QGraphicsItem::GraphicsItemFlag `flag`, bool `enabled` = true)
>
> Если `enable` равно true, флаг `flag` элемента включен; в противном случае он отключен.

Это [**перечисление описывает различные флаги**](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qgraphicsitem.html#GraphicsItemFlag-enum), которые вы можете установить для элемента, чтобы переключать различные функции в поведении элемента.

```
class RectItem(QGraphicsRectItem):
    def __init__(self, qrectf):
        super().__init__()
        self.qrectf = qrectf
        self.setRect(self.qrectf)
        
        self.setFlag(QGraphicsRectItem.ItemIsMovable, True)     # !!! +++ 
        
    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        print("hello")


class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.qrectf = QRectF(0, 0, 50, 50)
        self.item = RectItem(self.qrectf)
        self.scene = QGraphicsScene()
        self.scene.setSceneRect(0,0,200,300)
        self.scene.addItem(self.item)
        self.canvas = QGraphicsView()
        self.canvas.setScene(self.scene)

        layout = QHBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.canvas)
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Window()
    w.show()
    app.exec()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: выдаёт такую ошибку: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 35, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 23, in __init__
  File "<string>", line 13, in __init__
AttributeError: type object 'QGraphicsRectItem' has no attribute 'ItemIsMovable'

Comment: Заработало!  ```self.setFlag(QGraphicsRectItem.ItemIsMovable, True)``` заменил на ``self.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.GraphicsItemFlag.ItemIsMovable)```

Comment: @nikP да, в `PyQt6` это так.