# PyQt: экземпляр QRectF не обрабатывает событие мыши

Tags: python, pyqt6, qgraphicsscene, qgraphicsview, mousepressevent

Вот такой код.

```py
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt6.QtCore import *

import sys

class My_Rect (QRectF):
    
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(0,0, 100, 100)
    
    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        print(event.pos())
     
class My_Canvas(QGraphicsView):
    
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.graphScene = QGraphicsScene()
        self.m = My_Rect()
        self.graphScene.addRect(self.m)
        self.setScene(self.graphScene)
     
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = QWidget()
c = My_Canvas()
layout = QVBoxLayout()
layout.addWidget(c)
window.setLayout(layout)
window.show()
app.exec()
```

Непонятно, почему в экземпляре класса `My_Rect()` при щелчке мышью не выполняется  `mousePressEvent()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Класс [**QRectF**](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qrectf.html) определяет конечный прямоугольник на плоскости, используя точность с плавающей запятой. 
В [**List of All Members for QRectF**](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qrectf-members.html) нет метода `mousePressEvent()`.

Класс [**QGraphicsRectItem**](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qgraphicsrectitem.html) предоставляет прямоугольный элемент, который можно добавить в `QGraphicsScene`.
[**List of All Members for QGraphicsRectItem**](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qgraphicsrectitem-members.html) + QGraphicsItem::[**mousePressEvent**](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qgraphicsitem.html#mousePressEvent)(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event)

Прочитайте [**В чём разница между сценой и представлением в PyQt5?**](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1110849/%D0%92-%D1%87%D1%91%D0%BC-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%83-%D1%81%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%B2-pyqt5/1111074#1111074), я пытался что-то рассказать.

```
import sys
'''
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt6.QtCore import *
'''
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class CustomItem(QGraphicsRectItem):
    def __init__(self, parent = None, scene = None):
        super(CustomItem, self).__init__()

        self.setRect(200, 200, 120, 25)        

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        self.setBrush(QBrush(Qt.cyan))
        print(f'class CustomItem(QGraphicsRectItem): {event.pos()} # <--- QGraphicsRectItem ')
        super(CustomItem, self).mousePressEvent(event)
        

class My_Rect(QRectF):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(0, 0, 100, 100)

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        print(f'class My_Rect(QRectF): {event.pos()} # ??????????????? ')
        super(My_Rect, self).mousePressEvent(event)
        
        
class GraphicsScene(QGraphicsScene):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
    
    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        super(GraphicsScene, self).mousePressEvent(event)
        sp = event.scenePos()
        print(f'class GraphicsScene(QGraphicsScene): {sp} # <--- Scene ')
        
     
class My_Canvas(QGraphicsView):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.graphScene = GraphicsScene()    
        self.m = My_Rect()
        self.graphScene.addRect(self.m)
        self.setScene(self.graphScene)

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        super(My_Canvas, self).mousePressEvent(event)
        print(f'class My_Canvas(QGraphicsView): {event.pos()}\n')


class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.canvas = My_Canvas() 

        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.canvas)

        self.item = CustomItem() 
        self.canvas.graphScene.addItem(self.item)
        self.canvas.graphScene.update()
        
     
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Window()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]